# Zxing qr scanning blackberry crash

Tags: java, blackberry, crash, qr-code, zxing

I am implementing a QR code scanner for blackberry devices and I am using ZXing libraries to do so. This is for os 6+ by the way. The problem I am having is that sometimes, only sometimes, when the camera opens up to prepare scanning, the device will freeze and do a full reboot...

Otherwise it works most of the time, I am able to scan and decode the qr codes etc. However is just seems like it occasionally feels like crashing for no reason. I do not know if it is something with the camera or something in my code, but I will provide the code.

```
public void scanBarcode() {

    // First we create a hashtable to hold all of the hints that we can
    // give the API about how we want to scan a barcode to improve speed
    // and accuracy.
    Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();

    // The first thing going in is a list of formats. We could look for
    // more than one at a time, but it's much slower.
    Vector formats = new Vector();
    formats.addElement(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);

    // We will also use the "TRY_HARDER" flag to make sure we get an
    // accurate scan
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

    // We create a new decoder using those hints
    BarcodeDecoder decoder = new BarcodeDecoder(hints);

    // Finally we can create the actual scanner with a decoder and a
    // listener that will handle the data stored in the barcode. We put
    // that in our view screen to handle the display.
    try {
        _scanner = new BarcodeScanner(decoder, new MyBarcodeDecoderListener());
        _barcodeScreen = new MyBarcodeScannerViewScreen(_scanner);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }


    // If we get here, all the barcode scanning infrastructure should be set
    // up, so all we have to do is start the scan and display the viewfinder
    try {
        _scanner.stopScan();
        _scanner.getPlayer().start();
        _scanner.startScan();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(_barcodeScreen);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

/***
 * MyBarcodeDecoderListener
 * <p>
 * This BarcodeDecoverListener implementation tries to open any data encoded
 * in a barcode in the browser.
 * 
 * @author PBernhardt
 * 
 **/
private class MyBarcodeDecoderListener implements BarcodeDecoderListener {

    public void barcodeDecoded(final String rawText) {

        //UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
        UtilityDecoder.saveToHistory(rawText);

        try {
            UtilityDecoder.distributeBarcode(rawText);
        } catch (PIMException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

I basically call scanBarcode() when I click on a button on a toolbar.

Can anyone tell me if my code is the problem, or the device, or something else? Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: First see the sample demo name is "**BarcodeScan Demo**" provided from Version 6.0 onwards; 

Then you can understand all;

Comment: I have followed the demo and read the article.. as I said it works 95% of the time.. I am just getting weird crashes

Comment: Where you are getting crashes? I run that sample demo, it doesn't get any crashes and I created my own Barcode Scanning demo by taking the provided demo;;

Comment: Well then I guess it must be my blackberry device causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link:

[Scan Any Type of Barcode Image which Supports Blackberry](http://alishaik001.blogspot.in/2012/03/generate-our-own-qrcode-image-in.html)

See this forun link and see the discussions of that link. Surely, you will get overall concept of barcode scanning and you will also get the **Implemention of QRCode in version 5.0**

[Any type of Barcode scaning in 5.0](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/barcode-code-scanning/m-p/1561399#M190878)